# Custom module is not working in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I have created custom module in Magento but it does not work.

My module activation file is `app\etc\modules\Knowledge_Gain.xml`.

Below is my module activation code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Knowledge_Gain>   
            <active>true</active>  
            <codePool>local</codePool> 
        </Knowledge_Gain>
    </modules>
</config>`
```

My config file is `app\code\local\Knowledge\Gain\etc\config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Knowledge_Gain>
            <version>0.1.0</version> 
        </Knowledge_Gain>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <gain>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Knowledge_Gain</module>
                    <frontName>gain</frontName>
                </args>
            </gain>
        </routers>
        <layout>  
            <updates>
                <gain>
                    <file>gain.xml</file>
                </gain>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <gain>
                <class>Knowledge_Gain_Block</class>
            </gain>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>`
```

My controller file is `app\code\local\Knowledge\Gain\controllers\IndexController.php`

```
<?php
class Knowledge_Gain_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "Knowledge Gain Activated";
        $this->loadLayout();  
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

My block file is `app\code\local\Knowledge\Gain\Block\Trail.php`

```
<?php
class Knowledge_Gain_Block_Trail extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getContent()
    {
        return "Block Activated";
    }
```

And layout file is `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\gain.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <gain_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="gain/trail" name="gain" template="hello.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </gain_index_index>
</layout>`
```

And template file is `\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\hello.phtml`

```
<?php
echo $this->getContent();
echo get_class($this);
?>
```

What i am doing wrong in this code? The block content is not displayed.

Anyone please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: At first look your code looks correct. To test, move your layout XML file and template file into the base/default directory and see if it works then.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok. i have a check your module ,it's working.

Please clear cache 
System > Cache Management > click on "Flush Magento Cache" button

after check your module

Answer (score 0):

This module code is correct. In Magento ver 1.9.1 or above you need
to add new block in admin. Please follow few step:

Step 1:  Admin >> Permission >> Block >> Add new block and save the block.

Step 2:  System > Cache Management > click on "Flush Magento Cache" button.